# Angular Material SideNav autosize not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

I was using Angular Material to build a sidenav that can hide the nav text when onclick menu.
I follow the https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview  using autosize on mat-sidenav-container

But the sidenav still overlay the mat-sidenav-content part and it doesn't auto resize the content part

I using "@angular/material": "^8.0.2"

[image]
[image: n]

html

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container" autosize>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav class="example-sidenav" mode="side" opened="true">

    <mat-nav-list>
      <mat-list-item>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="isExpanded = !isExpanded">
          <mat-icon *ngIf="!isExpanded">chevron_right</mat-icon>
          <mat-icon *ngIf="isExpanded">chevron_left</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item>
       <mat-icon mat-list-icon>home</mat-icon>
         <p matLine *ngIf="isExpanded">Home</p>
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>

    Main content 

</mat-sidenav-content>

</mat-sidenav-container>
```

ts file

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material/sidenav';

@Component({
  selector: 'sidenav-autosize-example',
  templateUrl: 'sidenav-autosize-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['sidenav-autosize-example.css'],
})
export class SidenavAutosizeExample {
  isExpanded = false;
}
```

css

```
.example-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.example-sidenav-content {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: you want to hide completely the side nav(not partial) please create a stackblitz of your code(or edit stackblitz available on material site and edit accordingly what you have done till now)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Not necessary to use `autoSize`.
- Add attribute `[style.left]="sidenav.opened ? '.25%' : '0'"` to `mat-sidenav-content`.
- Not necessary to use `opened` attribute on `mat-sidenav`.
- Use attribue `[fixedInViewport]="false"` with `mat-sidenav`.

Comment: sidenav.opened unable to work but I use [style.left]="isExpanded ? '50px' : '0'" can work but it will missing proper align when resize the windows

Comment: Use `sidenav.toggle()` on `click` of button that regulates `sidenav`. Also, use `%` instead of `px` to get responsive experience.

Comment: the [style.left] will make the mat-sidenav-content position move to right and right part of content cannot show, how to make it auto resize responsive with [style.left] apply?

Answer (score 12):

You can easily fix this issue by adding **autosize="true"**

Example:

```
<mat-sidenav-container autosize="true">
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the above solution worked for me. I think the proper solution is to rather than setting the width of `<mat-sidenav></mat-sidenav>` in the CSS , set it to

```
min-width:50px
```

In order to resize according, you should be mentioning the **min-width** and **max-width** in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the element

```
<mat-sidenav-content>
```

I tried in many ways, this was the only one that worked